# UISplitViewController with story board

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, iphone-4

i am using story board with split view controller for iPad application.And set its initial to split view controller. I am populating the master view controller through an array. 'feature' is NSObject class where i declare method:

```
- (feature *)initWithName:(NSString *)name iconName:(NSString *)iconName featuresofiphone:(iphoneFeatures)featuresofiphone;
```

and returning name, iconName, featuresofiPhone of NSString type at its definition in .m class.
Here is my code at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
NSMutableArray *monsters = [NSMutableArray array];
[monsters  addObject:[[[feature alloc] initWithName:@"iphone3g" 
iconName:@"iphone3g.jpg" featuresofiphone:iphone3gf] autorelease]];

[monsters addObject:[[[feature alloc] initWithName:@"iphone3gs"  
iconName:@"iphone3gs.jpg" featuresofiphone:iphone3gsf] autorelease]];

[monsters addObject:[[[feature alloc] initWithName:@"iphone4g"  iconName:@"iphone4g.jpg"  
featuresofiphone:iphone4gf] autorelease]];

 MasterViewController *masterDetailViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
masterDetailViewController.iphones  = iphonesarray;

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
return YES;
```

but its giving exception:

```
 exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'
```

in master view controller at:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *) 
 [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
 [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] 
 animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

and control also not reaching to cellForRowAtIndexPath - method. help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough cells, just comment the line

```
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

it is trying to scroll to a cell that doesn't exist.